# jQuery Mobile Input checkbox displays double in IE10

Tags: jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-10

Using jQuery Mobile 1.3.  Here is the Rayzor code in my ASP.Net MVC page.

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { data_theme = "a" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { data_theme = "a" })
</li>
```

The resulting HTML renders as this in Chrome and looks the same in IE10 as well:
[image]

So far so good.  Now when I click inside this checkbox, OR when I tab to the control and press SPACE, IE starts to fail.  IE shows another checkbox on top of the one that's already there.

[image]

Not right!  A quick view of both browser's F12 screens does indeed show that this checkbox exists in the HTML.  Here it is highlighted in Chrome:

[image]

Is the proper solution to hide this with CSS?  If so, I would imagine this is a jQuery bug.  I cannot figure out why IE is showing this and Chrome is not.  In Chrome the display is set to block, and the zindex is set to 1.  So I would have expected it to show in Chrome as well.  Obviously I don't want it to; just seems IE is right in this case even though I want Chrome's behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code that populate checkbox.

JQM's checkbox has this input on top of lable. Like this...

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a">
    <label for="checkbox-2a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-on" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-checkbox-on ui-btn ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Doritos</span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-on ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This pointed me in the right direction. I flipped the rayzor I listed at the top, and generated the checkbox, then the label.  This fixed it.